# WPF MultiTrigger - Similar conditions on the same style

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, multitrigger

I'm trying to make a MultiTrigger condition but I need change this condition  based on the TextBlock Tag, if the Tag=0 run the first trigger and if Tag=1 run the another one. But in my code if the trigger condition where the Tag=0 ran and thereafter the Tag is changed to 1 the other trigger won't run.

I'm using this code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF333333"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFBEBEBE"/>
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="Tag" Value="0"/>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.300" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="Black" Duration="0:0:0.300" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#FFF0F2F3" Duration="0:0:0.300" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="Black" Duration="0:0:0.300" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="Tag" Value="1"/>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#222222" Duration="0:0:0.300" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="#FFFFFF" Duration="0:0:0.300" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#FF333333" Duration="0:0:0.300" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="#FFBEBEBE" Duration="0:0:0.300" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Some one knows what is wrong with this code? Or maybe it's possible.